# Push files on gitlab

Tags: git, gitlab, pull

I want to Push a file to GitLab and need SSH link
Is it in clone button?
Can we this SSH for pull and clone?
Is it same ?

[image]

Comment: You mean push or pull?

Comment: @MaikLowrey Push

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can find the SSH URL with the Clone button.

That will clone the full repository though, not just a file.

And it implies you already [registered a public SSH key to your GitLab profile](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ssh/#add-an-ssh-key-to-your-gitlab-account), for authentication.

That is mandatory when you want to push back a file, because GitLab needs to check if you have the right to do so. IE, to check if you are the owner of the target remote repository, or a declared collaborator.

Comment: Can We use it for pushing too?

Comment: @moh Yes, if you are the owner of,  or a collaborator for that remote repository.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

You can use an SSH key for pushing, pulling, cloning and every other git related command.

Think of it as your authentication to Gitlab Git servers.